# Weird error AS3. Term undefined

Tags: actionscript-3

so I'm getting an error at line 342 which is

```
myTextField.text = object[curPart]["text"]
```

it says that a term is undefined. Tracing curPart gives me a null value, although in code that runs literally moments for that one, curPart is part3. Nothing changes it. This is what runs before it, a type writing effect function.

```
private function addCharackter():void
{
    if (!textFinished)
    {
        // add the charackter to the Textfield
        myTextField.text = object[curPart]["text"].substring(0,counter)
        counter++
        trace(curPart) // prints "part3"
        // if you reached the end of the String stop Timer
        if (counter == object[curPart]["text"].length+1 && !textFinished)
        {
            textFinished = true;
            trace("Text finished:",textFinished)
            clearInterval(sInt)
            counter = 0;
            if (object[curPart]["text"].indexOf("What do you do?") >= 0)
            {
                trace("H!!!")
                choosing = true
                createOptions();
            }
            if (object[curPart]["text"].indexOf("What do you do?") >= 0)
            {
                dead = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another weird thing is that the error doesn't happen if I finish the type writing effect by pressing space which is done here:

```
public function onEnter(key:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (key.charCode == 32)
    {
        if (dead && textFinished && !choosing)
        {
            curPart = object[curPart]["lastPart"]
            textFinished = false
            dead = false;
            myTextField.text = ""
            counter = 0;
            sInt = setInterval(addCharackter, textSpeed)
        }
        if (!textFinished && !choosing && !dead)
        {
            trace(textFinished)
            trace("finishing")
            trace(curPart)
            myTextField.text = object[curPart]["text"]
            if (object[curPart]["text"].indexOf("What do you do?") >= 0)
            {
                trace("H!")
                choosing = true
                createOptions();
            }
            if (object[curPart]["text"].indexOf("You have died") >= 0)
            {
                dead = true;
            }
            clearInterval(sInt)
            textFinished = true;
        }
        else if (textFinished && !choosing && !dead)
        {
            trace("Hi!!!!")
            curPart = object[curPart]["nextPart"]
            myTextField.text = ""
            counter = 0;
            sInt = setInterval(addCharackter, textSpeed)
            textFinished = false
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked through my code for hours. text is inside part3 and part3 DOES exist, considering it works if I skip the typing process by pressing space. (it also doesn't happen if I were to skip the typing process before part3.)

edit: Another thing that I just realised, line 342 should never be ran because textFinished should equal true (which it is moments before, but when I press space, it magically isn't. I don't change it to false anywhere except in parts that aren't running when the error happens)

Comment: FWIW, you could probably streamline your code by just storing a reference to currentObject (currentObject = object[curPart]) and then just referring to that everywhere. And storing its text once, rather than rereading the full reference every time you want to check something about the text. Finally, "object" is a terrible name for a variable. It might be in conflict with a reserved word.

Comment: I know object is terrible. I named it that for testing and never changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found why it wasn't working. Stupid user error.